# How can at execute a command from the command line

Tags: linux, command-line, unix, scheduled-tasks, at

How can I schedule a command using `at` without having to include the command in a distinct file, neither from the mini `at` shell that reads from standard input?

That is, I want to execute the command:

```
find /path -name "pattern" > output.lst
```

after X minutes.

A plausible try was

```
at now +X minutes find /path -name "pattern" > output.lst
```

but obviously it did not work.

If you are wondering why I want something like this, is because I want to include it within a scirpt where X and "pattern" are parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`at` read the command from standard input (or a file if you specify it with `-f`).

This should work:

```
echo 'find /path -name "pattern" > output.lst' | at now +X minutes
```

Comment: Right on! Thx!!!